# two-pane in SettingsActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences

```
Editor :- Android Studio
compileSdkVersion 23
```

I have add a PreferenceActivity in my application. For phone device its working fine. I want to customize my settings to show two-pane in landscape mode of Nexus 7 or other tablet. Single-Pane in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new xml-config file for each activity concerning landscape mode.

You find it here:

[image: Screenshot]